# How do I pull an item from array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to remove an item from `session_users`. The purpose of `users` is to have a reference to an user that has joined a session. `session_users` on the other hand have a reference to the user and some data that is only valid during that session.

I get `session` and `user` as a reference for that session and user I want to remove, which does work fine in other code.

Here is an example of a session exported from MongoDB Compass:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61a73bf460a73d52d4566546"
    },
    "access_code": "7297230688",
    "session_users": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61a73bf460a73d52d4566545"
        },
        "last_active": {
            "$date": "2021-12-01T09:10:13.810Z"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "$oid": "61a722231970630db48cf518"
        },
        "user_status": "ACTIVE"
    }],
    "users": [{
        "$oid": "61a722231970630db48cf518"
    }],
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have tried these two solutions:

```
await session.session_users.pull({ session_users: { user_id: user._id }})
await session.session_users.pull({ user_id: user._id })
```

I use similar code to pull the user reference from the users array, which does work:

```
await session.users.pull(user)
```

I have also tried to get a `session_user` object as a reference similar to how `user` is, and use that to pull it from the array, but that doesn't work either. I have also tried to use `findByIdAndUpdate`  with `$pull` using several different methods of trying to write the query.

To me it seems based on countless problems people have with the `pull` feature is that it is buggy, but I don't think I can get the item out of the array any other way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do:

```
sessionModel.updateOne( { _id: YOUR_SESSION_ID }, { $pull: { session_users: { user_id: YOUR_USER_ID } } } )
```

Comment: Thanks! Just needed to add ```..., { new: true }``` to the end and used ```findByIdAndUpdate``` instead and it started working